# Usage of prepositions “of” and “for” in a title

Tags: prepositions

I am puzzled by the title of my academic thesis. It can be entitled as

> Research on Key Technologies **of** Implementing xxx.

or

> Research on Key Technologies **for** Implementing xxx.

I mean we develop the key technologies which are used in implementing xxx. We do to it for some propose like improving the quality or efficiency of the implementation results.

So which one is better, or any other suggestions.

Comment: Are the key technologies required to implement xxx or is xxx a tool/process used in the key technologies?

Comment: The key technologies are required to implement xxx better.

Comment: Perhaps "A study of key technologies for the implementation of xxx".

Answer (score -2):

It is better to use **of implementing** xxx. 'For implementing xxx' is not appropriate.

We usually use the -ing form after a preposition. We **don't use 'for'** before a verb to talk about purpose.

We can also use *to + infinitive*.

'**to implement** xxx'

Comment: It may that the key technologies have the purpose of implementing xxx. If that's the case you have argued successfully for ***for.***

Comment: I accept the comment from Peter，“A study of key technologies for the implementation of xxx”.